# How to animate div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

Hi I can change and toggle the div attributes on scroll but when I use animate, it won't work but in weird manner.

The following works:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
$("#register").css({left: $(this).scrollLeft() > 1348? "-140px":"0px"});
});
```

But this won't work:

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
$("#register").animate({left: $(this).scrollLeft() > 1348? "-140px":"0px"});
});
```

I want the div to go away when I scroll more than 1348, and if the scroll is less than 1348, the div should appear again.

Simple css works but animation doesn't work.

Comment: On every single registered scroll event, CSS applies changes not visible to the eye, means, it always redraws the element at 0px left if document.scrollLeft is < 1348. Animate will do an **animate** on every single scroll tick. What have you done to prevent that?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using skrollr.js

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

typical usage as simple as :

```
<div data-0="background-color:rgb(0,0,255);" data-500="background-color:rgb(255,0,0);">WOOOT</div>
```

where data-number represents current scroll position.

animation can be done using css transit .

Comment: Does the plugin adds support for horizontal scrolling?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes for sure , i recommend it cause the performance of css is much better than jquery animate.

Comment: Actually I'm amazed how smooth the result is in FF!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you are interested in smoothness i would recommend you read this article http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation , really useful ;)